# Difference: "have been" and "was"

Tags: present-tense, past-simple

Can anyone please tell me what the difference between "**have been**" and "***was***" in the following sentence is?

Here is the text:

I *have been/was* a big fan of Tottenham football club but from now on I will never support the team. It is because of the rude behaviour to other footballers in the last match a have come to this conclusion.

Note that before that incident happened, I was a big fan of the team. I am not a fan any more.

Comment: Have you looked up the difference between the [simple past ("was")](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-past-tense/) and the [present perfect ("have been")](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/)?

Comment: @stangdon Hi, yes I have and I know the difference. But I am a little confused because there are some situations where both tenses can be used. I think the above sentence is one of those. Therefore, if you please explain whether I can use both tenses in that sentence, that'll be very helpful.

Comment: @user254288 Using **was** or **used to be** instead of **have been** signals at the start of the sentence that you are no longer a fan. **Have been** fails to give this early warning. So it depends on what you want to indicate.

Answer (score 1):

"Have been" refers to something that you still are, for example "I have been a fan of that sports team for years." "Was", similarly to "used to be", similar to "had been", are all expressing that you are no longer, for example "I was/used to be/had been a fan of that sports team, but now I am not."